# Query editor for hibernate (Spring roo project)

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, editor

I'm new to java, hibernate, spring roo and spring mvc.
I'm using Hibernate annotations and POJO classes.
My IDE is Spring Source (based on Eclipse)

What hibernate query editor do you suggest for testing hibernate queries?

I've tried installing jboss hibernate tools for eclipse, but had no success in configuration.
When I try to browse Database, I'm getting this error

> An internal error occurred during:
>   "Fetching children of Database".
>   org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

I've tried to configure maven to use older version slf4j (1.5.8) but that didn't resolved the issue.

I've found recommendation for HQE editor,
but it's not available https://hqe.dev.java.net (Not found)

What is the easiest way to try Hibernate Queries? What tool do you suggest?

Comment: May it is only a not so correct wording, but Spring Roo is based on JPA, and there for you should use JQL but not HQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why we need query editor for hibernate. Since the idea of hibernate was to make sure normal java developers can write query without sql knowledge. 
When I developed hql, I used to just create join using java objects in eclipse. and then copy that to the query. And run the application to see if the query is fetching desired result. This method is tiresome, but still you don't write much of queries in hibernate, and also you will get used to syntax with just few queries.
And usually you will fetch by lazy loading and never use hql.

Still if you have a better way, I will check this blog.

Comment: For simple queries that's true, but for complex queries I need HQL. It would be nice if some kind of tool existed to allow ad-hoc execution of HQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try Squirrel. It can do queries using hibernate.

Comment: Two ways you might improve your answer:  1) Include a link to Squirrel.  2) Give a couple reasons why do you are recommending it.